# Covergence or Divergence of Sequence with Term $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{a^n}{x^n+n^a}$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, convergence-divergence, real-numbers

I have a sequence whose convergence or divergence needs to be proved, it's represented by term below.

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{a^n}{x^n+n^a}$$ and here's what I tried to dobut taking ratio of terms does not seem to be leading to any results

$$\frac{T_n}{T_{n+1}} = a[\frac{x^n+n^a}{x^{n+1}+(n+1)^a}]$$

If I assume $n^a$ is the bigger term so above fraction becomes

$$ a[\frac{1+\frac{x^n}{n^a}}{(1+\frac{1}{n})^a+\frac{x^{n+1}}{n^a}}]$$

now denominator becomes $1+\frac{a}{n}+...\frac{x^{n+1}}{n^a}$ and since $n \to \infty$

we get $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{T_n}{T_{n+1}}=a$$ but this is when I did not assume anything related to $x$ and $a$ relative to each other.

So I tried root test where

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} ({T_n})^{\frac{1}{n}} = \frac{a}{(x^n+n^a)^{\frac{1}{n}}}$$

which can be written as $$\frac{a}{x(1+\frac{n^a}{x^n})^{\frac{1}{n}}}$$ which further expands the denominator to 
$$\frac{a}{x(1+\frac{n^{a-1}}{x^n})}$$ now assuming $n^{a-1}$ is a very big term denominator becomes $\infty$ and whole thing collapses to 0, which by Cauchy's Root test <1 and hence convergent

But I am not sure if I am doing it correctly or not, a little helping hand will be deeply appreciated.

Regards

Sid

Comment: Indeed $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{n^{a-1}}{x^n} = +\infty$ when $a>1$. For $0<a<1$ the limit is zero.

Comment: Does either $a$ or $x$ have any restrictions?

Comment: @Math1000 How do you arrive at that result?  Suppose $x=2$ and $a=2$.  Then, $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n^{a-1}}{x^n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n}{2^n}=0$$

Comment: @Math1000 When $x>1$ the limit is $0$ for every $a$.

Comment: I meant for $|x|<1$, sorry.